# How to best append element name to each HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

CSS `::after` has a nice feature in combination with `content` and `attr()`, that lets you insert any attr value as the pseudo-element content.

For general debugging purposes, I'm looking to append a little yellow label to all HTML elements with the content as name of the element.

I can do ids and classes with CSS.

But for elements (`p` `div` `span` etc) javascript is the only option?

Comment: same way : attr(name);  ... unless i misunderstood your unclear question :=

Comment: You're talking about name attribute. I mean elements themselves "p", "div", "span", etc. Clarified question.

Comment: Yes javascript is the only way :)

Comment: You're welcome to post that as your answer.

Comment: Just did and setted an example via jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to use javascript or jQuery that makes it much easier : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HrJAI)**

HTML test

```
<div>
</div>
<p></p>
<form></form>  
<span></span>
```

CSS test

```
[data-tag]:before {content:attr(data-tag);}
```

jQuery

```
$("body").children().each(function() {
  var domel= $(this).get(0);
  $(this).attr("data-tag",domel.nodeName);
})
```

it produces this :

```
<div data-tag="DIV"></div>
```

Comment: Mhm, this is exactly what I was thinking of doing.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can [select](http://api.jquery.com/select/) all elements of a certain type/tag, I'd recommend using that.

Comment: Yes, jQuery it certainy will be, but that "select" link seems to be related to text selection event. I'm basically just doing *::after here.

Comment: Gotcha. Looks like there's an .after() function, could try something like:
    `$().after( 'this content's name' );` or whatever you'd like.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to do the following and you do not need javascript.

http://jsbin.com/wepayija/3/edit

```
<style>
p::after {
  background-color: yellow;
  content: 'p'
}

.my-class::after {
  background-color: green;
  content: 'p'
}

div:after {
  background-color: yellow;
  content: 'div'
}
</style>

<p>I have no class</p>
<p class="my-class">I have a class</p>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't give me the element name itself in the ::after "tooltip".